# openssl-legacy-provider error when compile

Tags: spring-boot, openssl, vaadin

I am trying to learn Vaadin with spring boot but when ever I compile the code,its always showing erro when frontend part start the compilation

```
------------------ Starting Frontend compilation. ------------------
2022-06-12 21:50:58.951  INFO 9764 --- [nPool-worker-19] c.v.b.devserver.AbstractDevServerRunner  : Running Webpack to compile frontend resources. This may take a moment, please stand by...
2022-06-12 21:50:58.965  INFO 9764 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : /usr/bin/node: --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS

------------------ Frontend compilation failed. ------------------
```

I am running node v16.15 and jdk 17
Facing this problem when i use linux base system but not happening on window with the same node version
Tried to use **unset NODE_OPTIONS** but not working

Any suggestion please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an issue with openssl3 see issue https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/13889
It should probably be fixed in node 16.16